# Azure Virtual Machine SSL for port other than 443

Tags: azure, ssl, virtual-machine

I cant seem to get secure content through port 8080 to an Azure VM.

Regular SSL traffic through port 443 is fine, However when setting an endpoint for port 8080 and then trying to access it I'm receiving the following error:

handshake to www.... failed. System.IO.IOException Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Firewall Inbound and Outbound rules have been created.

Certificate is the same one that is being used for port 443 traffic without any issue.

thank you for your help.

the output from openssl s_client -connect is:

CONNECTED(0000019C)
27308:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:.\ssl\s23_lib.c:177:

no peer certificate available

No client certificate CA names sent

SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 321 bytes

New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE

error in s_client

### edit (solved):

The issues seems to be a bug in NodeJS. I downgraded from 0.10.29 to 0.10.26 and now everything works as expected.

Comment: What is the URL to the server? Or what is the output of `openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port>`?

Comment: Please place the information in your question by clicking *Edit*. As you can see, its impossible to read when you put it in a comment. After you add it to the question, please delete it from the comment to keep the area clutter free.